# Get productimage based on SKU

Tags: product, magento-1, product-images

I want to display the productimage, based on the SKU of the product.

How can I achieve this?

My currenty code in a custom module, that displays the SKU based on the following code:

```
<?php echo $item->getProduct() ? $item->getProduct()->getSku() : Mage::helper('rma')->getOrderItemLabel($item) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `$item` object then you can easily get the product image by like this,

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($item->getProduct()->getSmallImage());
```

But still If you want the product Image based on `SKU` then you can get it like this,

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getProduct()->getSku());

    $imageUrl=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getSmallImage());
```

Comment: There is no `loadBySku` method. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18421/why-cant-i-load-a-product-by-sku-using-loadbysku

Comment: Yes, thanks for the letting me know :) I updated my answer and +1 from me @sv3n

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);
$product->getData('image');
$product->getData('thumbnail');
$product->getData('small_image');
```

Answer (score 1):

Keyur Shah first part is correct, but there is no `loadBySku` method as suggested in 2nd part. For loading products by SKU you should use

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);
```

To keep the loaded data as small as possible you can add a 3rd parameter with attribute codes you want to load, e.g.

```
$attributes = array('image', 'thumbnail');
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku, $attributes);
```

<sup>(Default value for 3rd parameter is `'*'`, so it will load all attributes)</sup>